# boundary of a square in the complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that if C is the boundary of the square with vertices at the points z = 0, z = 1,
z = 1 + i, z = i and the orientation of C is counterclockwise, then
(Integral over C)
(3z + 1)dz = 0

I am confused with this question

Any hints on how to start this will be highly appreciated

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You have three choices, depending on how much theory and how much elbow grease you want to use.

1. Parametrize the four sides, and use the definition of complex curve integrals on each.
2. Parametrize the four sides, and use the complex version of the fundamental theorem of calculus on each. (You should be able to find an anti-derivative easily.) If you are clever, there s a shortcut here, since the curve is closed.
3. Use Cauchy's integral theorem.

Answer (score 0):

0

Show that if C is the boundary of the square with vertices at the points z = 0, z = 1, z = 1 + i, z = i and the orientation of C is counterclockwise, then (Integral over C) (3z + 1)dz = 0

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).